# A simpler way to capture multiple variables in javascript regexps

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Comming from the perl/python world I was wondering if there is a simpler way to filter out multiple captured variables from regexp in javascript:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node  
var data=[
  "DATE: Feb 26,2015",
  "hello this should not match"
];

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  var re = new RegExp('^DATE:\\s(.*),(.*)$');
  if(data[i].match(re)) {
    //match correctly, but how to get hold of the $1 and $2 ?
  }
  if(re.exec(data[i])) {
    //match correctly, how to get hold of the $1 and $2 ? 
  }

  var ret = '';
  if(data[i].match(re) && (ret = data[i].replace(re,'$1|$2'))) {
    console.log("line matched:" + data[i]);
    console.log("return string:" + ret);
    ret = ret.split(/\|/g);
    if (typeof ret !== 'undefined') {
      console.log("date:" + ret[0], "\nyear:" + ret[1]);
    }
    else {
      console.log("match but unable to parse capturing parentheses");
    }
  }
}
```

The last condition works, but you need a temp var and split it, and you need to have a test in front because the replace works on everything.

Output is:

```
$ ./reg1.js 
line matched:DATE: Feb 26,2015
return string:Feb 26|2015
date:Feb 26 
year:2015
```

If I look up: [mosdev regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) it says on (x):

> The matched substring can be recalled from the resulting array's
>   elements [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), ..., [n] or from the predefined RegExp object's
>   properties $1, ..., $9.

How do I get hold of the RegExp objects' $1 and $2?

Thanks

Comment: What does `match` return? And no, it's not a trick question - look in the API.

Comment: .match() return a commareparated string, I'm unable to set the delimiter like in .replace(re, '$1|$2') makes it hard when you have commas in Your strings.

Comment: @Match doesn't return a comma separated string. It returns an array

Comment: Found .match() and .exec() returned arrays. did not see it when Iprinted the object. but if you explicily probe for them they are there, then the delimitier does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) is a good resource for learning Javascript. In this particular case, `.match()`, `.exec()`, etc. all return objects containing match information. That is where you'll find captured groups.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer found that they return an array:, so the simpler blocks can look like this:

```
  if((ret = data[i].match(re))!=null) {
    //match correctly, but how to get hold of the $1 and $2 ?
    console.log("line matched:" + data[i]);
    console.log("return string:" + ret[0] + "|" + ret[1]);
    ret = null;
  }
  if((ret = re.exec(data[i]))!=null) {
    //match correctly, how to get hold of the $1 and $2 ?
    console.log("line matched:" + data[i]);
    console.log("return string:" + ret[0] + "|" + ret[1]);
    ret = null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript [.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) and [.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) this can be very simple

An example:

```
var input = "DATE: Feb 26, 2015",
    regex = /^DATE:\s*(.*),\s*(.*)$/;

if (regex.match(input)) {
    console.log('Matches Format!');

    //.match() needs splicing because .match() returns the actually selected stuff. It becomes weirder with //g  
    var results = input.match(regex).splice(0,1);

    console.log(results);
    //Logs: ["Feb 26", "2015"]
}
```

[Regex101](http://regex101.com) can be useful